# How to authenticate users to my site?

Tags: security

I simply want people to authenticate themselves when typing in my website URL. For example, I saw an article on 10/20/14 that said that FX was coming out with a website for the Simpsons called 'simpsonsworld.com' so I visited the site (to check it out). However, later in the article it said that the site was not becoming live until 10/21/14 (today). When I typed in 'simpsonsworld.com' into the URL, a dropdown box asked me to authenticate myself (username & password). When you visit the site today (10/21), the site is completely visible.

How do I get this drop-down box when someone types in 'myurl.com'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.htaccess` and `.htpassword`. From http://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess

.htaccess should contain

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /the/path/youre/protecting/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

.htpasswd should contain

`username:password`

Comment: Thank you very much! This did exactly what I wanted to do. However, I'm using host-gator for web hosting and after I type in the correct usrename and password, host-gator is throwing a 500 error (server error). Do you know why this is?

Comment: AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /index.html
Require valid-user                  

This is what my .htaccess file looks like

Comment: Oh, your problem is you need to list the path to the .htpassword file, not the index.html.

Comment: Geez, I would have no idea what to do if it wasn't for you! Thank you Parker! cheers

Comment: No problem! Be sure to mark the answer as the solution so others can use this to help if they have the same problem